# How to create one .mbtiles from thousands of GeoTIFFs?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mbtiles

I have about 7000 of Geotiffs (3600x2400px each).

I want to make a single .mbtiles file from them.

Can you tell me, how can I do it?

Comment: Well, I can also use Python or C++, but I don't know which library to use.

Comment: Have you tried ogr tools?

Comment: Well, just now I'm going to try gdalwarp...

Comment: Greate a virtual mosaic with gdalbuildvrt and then convert .vrt into .mbtiles wiht gdal_translate. Warping should happen automatically in this case because MBTiles support only Web Mercator.